# where function setCategoryId defined in statement $params->setCategoryId

Tags: magento-2.0

In module_catalog , `Controller/Prodcut/View.php` file, Can you please explain what is the purpose of DataObject Class and where `function setCategoryId` defined ?

```
// Prepare helper and params
        $params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `DataObject` is to wrap the array of parameters in an object so it can be passed as a reference to other methods (most probably an event observer).
The method `setCategoryId` does not exist. Through the "magic" of `__call` it is transformed to `setData('category_id', $categoryId)`